# Functional prototype of a function containing pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-prototypes

I have a simple question which is not easily found. Lets say I want to make a functional prototype for a function containing pointers, for example:

```
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
```

Is there any special rules for function prototypes regarding pointers? Or will the functional prototype for this be:

```
int insert(char, char, int)
```

Comment: You could try to compile it and see for yourself.  (Hint: that's not the right prototype.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write the prototype without parameter names, it will be

```
int insert(char *, char **, int);
```

The type of the first argument is `char *`. The type of the second argument is `char **` (recall that as a parameter, `char *Table[]` really means `char **Table`). The type of the third argument is `int`. The return type is `int`.

You don't have to leave out the parameter names, by the way. This works too:

```
int insert(char *word, char **Table, int n);
```

or:

```
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n);
```

Comment: Thank you for the well written answer! I have just recently gotten back into C and its overwhelming to try to learn everything again from just guides and videos.